# is it possible to play avaudioplayer in background mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I am doing an Alarm application,in my app after lunching app in device i am saving one alarm and i close the app.When alarm is coming, its not ringing But at that time update method is calling i am getting notification. after that i set another alarm and i keep the app open at that time i got both alarm sound and one alertview after that all the alarms are also coming in background mode with sound.

I did change in info.plist in Required background modes and in coding also i am doing like this

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationErr];
```

Please suggest me what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

For alarm purpouses it's better to use Local notifications or Calendar, I think.